# Bug introduced in Area 51 close voting changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, vote-to-close

When I clicked to close a proposal because the proposal was **poorly defined**, I was instead given the **duplicate of site** reason box.

I think you guys may need to check your jQuery or Ajax related code.  You probably forgot to do the correct math or update your tables on the reason response, now that there's a new reason to select.

Comment: Is this still happening for you (after refreshing)? I'm unable to reproduce it. I deployed the change right around the time you posted this question, so it's possible that you loaded the page *before* I deployed, then loaded the close-reasons-popup-box *after* I deployed, so the server & client-side code were out of sync.

Comment: @Emmett - I'll clear my stuff out and give it a shot.

Comment: @Emmett - I did a full refresh with Firefox and got the same bug, then I tried in IE8 (with full refresh) and got the same bug.  So it looks like it's real.  Maybe there's a small caching issue, or something.

Comment: @Emmett - I voted to close again for a different reason and still got the duplicate of site reason box.

Comment: @Mark Ah, there was a typo in the javascript. Pushing a fix.. sorry about that.

Comment: @Emmett - I can't say I haven't done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for the report, and for your persistence after I denied the bug's existence.